# Mediation for mixed model with crossed factors in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, mediation

I am looking for a possibility to test for mediation in a scenario where the individual paths (M ~ X, Y ~ M + X) are represented by mixed models with crossed factors (with binary x and continuous m):

```
library(lme4)
mod_med <- lmer(m ~ (1|r) + (1|s) + x, data=df)
mod_y <- lmer(y ~ (1|r) + (1|s) + x + m, data=df)
```

For cases with a single random intercept I have been happily using the *mediation* package by Tingley et al., however it fails in this case.

```
library(mediation)
full <- mediate(mod_med, mod_y, treat = 'y', mediator = 'm')
Error in mediate([...]) : mediate does not support more than two levels per model
```

I would like to avoid using the Sobel test; hence I have considered using SEM, but have not found a package that appeared to be appropriate for random effects and mediation testing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Asking for R code / packages is off topic here. You could ask how to formulate this situation as an SEM model, though.

Comment: Thank you. I worded my question poorly. It is not so much a package that I seek, but a suitable approach to mediation given the above scenario. Accordingly, any help with formulating an SEM equivalent to the above would be much appreciated (e.g., using lavaan).
I am fairly unfamiliar with SEM and would like to make sure that I do not alter the underlying question and assumptions when translating this into SEM.

Comment: Have you found a suitable option? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The mediate function in the mediation package takes only a binary mediator or a numeric mediator. In your case, it seems that your mediator is categorical but contains more than 2 levels. You can either convert it to numeric or dummy code it.

Comment: I face the same problem, but my mediator is a double. I guess mediation can not handle yet crossed random factors.